# How can I clear the cache of an IOS Web App on the Homescreen?

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, jqtouch, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am using JQTouch to create a Web App on the Homescreen using meta tag "apple-mobile-web-app-capable", but no matter how many times I clear the cache from within Settings, the Web App's Javascript is still an older cached version.

Strangely enough, if I set the meta tag's content to;

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no" />
```

...then add the Web App to the Homescreen, I get the latest version when I launch it.

Yet if I set the meta tag to;

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

...then add the Web App to the Homescreen, I get the older cached version.

PS. I can confirm that is **only the javascript** which will not refresh.

Answer (score 20):

You could try adding a unique string to the end of your js include's src attribute (use a timestamp, for example). Bear in mind you'll have to change this unique string for each refresh you want to do, so you may want to consider doing lazy-loading (which may in itself solve your problem):
`<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js?012345"></script>`

This usually forces the browser into grabbing the latest version of the script. Might work...

Comment: Same technique works for CSS files. <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?3432">

Comment: And images : `<img src="foo.png?12345" />`

Comment: unbelievable, I've been breaking my head on this for a whole day (css problem for me). A similar problem exists with Silverlight, unbelievable that 2 mayor companies make these kind of BUGS! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, My problem doesn't regard the controlled resources, I have a cookie which makes an infinite loop which cause an error "too many redirections" on my app. I tried every possible way to delete the cache without success. any ideas how to clear the cookie?

Comment: Good solution, but my web application loads old version on index.html :))

Comment: Yeah, the only way that seems to work in iOS 10 is to change the URL for the HTML file in a similar way *and* add versioning for all other files referenced by the HTML.  This might also be solved by adding a cache manifest, but only if you remember to add the cache manifest initially.  Otherwise, the old HTML that lacks a cache manifest will get cached permanently, and you're back to adding ?version=1 to the HTML URL.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a way that worked for me to clear **completely** the cache:

1-Delete the tabs in safari where there is your app.
2-Delete the icon of the app in the home screen.
3-[Kill](http://ipod.about.com/od/iphonetroubleshooting/qt/quit_iphone_app.htm) safari from the memory.
4-Go to settings/safari and press clear cache.
*5-You can restart your iPhone/iPod if you want to be sure that it works*

Comment: This is the exact same procedure I used to use but since iOS 6 it doesn't seem to be working, the homescreen app still picks up cached data.

Comment: Please be aware if you do that **you will lose opened Safari tabs**. If you have something interesting for later reading there it will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using [bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) feature in ASP.NET MVC solved this problem for me.

It automatically generates a bundled link of the form:

http://www.domain.com/MvcBM_time/bundles/AllMyScripts?v=r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81

The token after the v= changes if any file in the bundle changes, guaranteeing that browser requests for the bundle will get the latest bundle.

Comment: Only issue with that is that Visual Studio's browser link feature doesn't work with bundling.

Comment: @rookie1024 VS BrowserLink does in fact work with bundling. Are you using Mads Kristensen's extension here - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40 ?

Comment: @HumbleBeginnings No, I am not, however I now know that BrowserLink only loses track of files if you have `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` set to `true` in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are jailbroken, just do this in the terminal

```
rm ./Library/Caches/com.apple.webapp/Cache.db
```

Comment: There's no such file on my iOS 5.1.1 device, and still my main.js is  taken from cache (regular safari gets a file from server ok though)

Answer (score 0):

This drove me absolutely nuts. I tried killing Safari, clearing the cache, switching to private mode, and removing the web app from the home screen. None of those work, but what does work is *temporarily loading the web app page in Safari itself and reloading*.

If you're using [add to home screen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen), you can add ?web_app_ready=1 to the install URL. Since that's not an end user procedure, adding a query string to every script (the answer above) will probably be more effective for non-developer environments.

Comment: I've tried that.  It used to work in iOS 6 or so, but it doesn't seem to work in iOS 10.

Comment: Yeah I don't know if this is valid in the latest version.

Comment: And in iOS 10, it caches the HTML, too, so specifying a ?foo=... to the resource doesn't work because it never sees the updated version of the HTML with the new URL.  Basically, caching of home-screen web apps is hopelessly broken at this point unless you have a cache manifest (and maybe even then—I haven't tried yet).

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what SquareFeet said, one could automatically pull the new file down every time with a unique GET tag appended to the filename, using PHP. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css?
   <?php echo(mt_rand(10000000, 99999999)); ?>
" />
```

Theoretically, the same task could be accomplished using JavaScript, albeit with some modifications to the web server:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css?
   <div id="id"></div>
" />

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
</script>
```